# Make MD5 of All Words in Wordlist

Tags: md5, rainbowtable

Let say we have a Wordlist with words

What i want to is to Genate Them to MD5 Hashes. 
(Have a 30gb Wordlist, i want to make All of they to MD5)
I dont care which language.

This say I have The Word "Test" in the wordlist 
So i want it in this format :

```
test:098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 = Test in MD5

Comment: Operating system, programming language?

Comment: I can't see the problem here. Iterate over the list and apply an MD5-Hash on each.

Comment: What, are you making a rainbow table?  You don't sound like you'd really know how to use it for anything.

Comment: Smells like a hacker to me. Nice name, too.  Shunning.

Answer (score 3):

bash ftw! \o/

```
while read word; do
    echo -n $word | md5sum -1 | cut -f 1 -d " "
done < wordlist
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySql: 
(might need to make the "TERMINATED BY" be '\n' on unix platforms.)

```
create table words ( word varchar(255) , hash varchar(32) );
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'wordlist'
    INTO TABLE words LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (word);
update words set hash=md5(word);
select * from words where word = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

in python:

```
import hashlib
word_list = ['test','word1','word2','third']
hash_dict = dict([(w,hashlib.md5(w).hexdigest()) for w in word_list])
for (k,v) in hash_dict.items(): print '%s:%s' % k,v
```

Added bonus: hash_dict['word'] gives you back that word's hash.